# Login connection data and time

Tags: sql-server, logins

I wonder if there is a way to query SQL Server to find out dates and times a login has connected to a particular server?

Comment: You have to have this setup ahead of time.  But your choices are to 1) Log all connections both successful and failed, 2) an Extended Event or 3) a logon trigger.

Comment: @JonathanFite LOL, if you left half of your comments as answers, you'd be at 10k uip (useless internet points) by now!

Comment: Maybe, but these types of questions typically require *more* work to answer well, and I just didn't want to devote that much time to it.  If some more enterprising soul wants to do a better job of outlining options with links and pictures, I'll upvote them.